# Uninstall Pylance and Flake8 from Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pylance, flake8

I have been using [Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/) and [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html) for a while, but now I don’t think I need them anymore, and they’re bothering me a lot since there are a lot of rules to follow. How I uninstall them from my Visual Studio Code and even from my PC?

I know there is a way to disable them in settings, but I’d rather just uninstall them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps below should solve your problem:

In Visual Studio Code, click the extensions icon in the activity Bar on the side of the window. In the Extensions view, search for "Pylance" and "Flake8".

Click on the gear icon next to the installed extensions (Pylance and Flake8) and select "Uninstall" from the context menu.

Another way, which is the easiest way, is below.

```
pip uninstall pylance
pip uninstall flake8
```

If you used [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) to install the extensions, run the following commands:

```
conda uninstall pylance
conda uninstall flake8
```

After executing the appropriate commands, Pylance and Flake8 will be uninstalled from your PC and Visual Studio Code environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package manager to install/uninstall libraries.

If you use pip (package installer for Python), you can command like this in terminal.

1. Uninstall [Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/)

   ```
   pip uninstall pylance
   ```
2. Uninstall [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html)

   ```
   pip uninstall flake8
   ```

You can disable or uninstall by using the Visual Studio Code extension service:

1. Click the extension icon on the left side bar.
2. Find out your extensions (Pylance and Flake8)
3. Click the <kbd>Uninstall</kbd> button
4. Reboot Visual Studio Code or your computer.

If it still exists in your Visual Studio Code, you should find the local cache files on your desktop.